# Simple Web UI for executing commands

Tags: gui, web, dashboard, home-automation

### What do I need?

I need a simple WebUI that allows to define buttons for shell commands.

#### Use cases:

- GUI for simple API calls from Postman via curl
- Trigger WakeOnLAN
- Restart application via SSH or local
- Run small script via SSH or local
- Trigger Function App

### Requirements

#### Must have

- Simple WebUI
- Simple role based access

  - Admin can define buttons
  - User can only execute a set of commands an admin has published for that user
  - Credentials can be hidden / are protected once command button has been created
- Selfhosting possible

#### Optional requirements

- Simple parameters are possible to enter via simple form
- Python based a plus
- If possible not Java based
- Small enough to run on a Raspberry Pi is a plus
- Dockerized is a plus
- Accessible via phone is a plus
- Re-export of buttons via API is a plus

### Ideas

- Tools like Rundeck, Ansible, Jenkins

  - focussed on automation or CI/CD; more simpler tool needed
- [SSH Button](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pd7l.sshbutton&hl=de&gl=US)

  - no webapp; access only via single phone
- NodeRED

  - dashboard not the main focus of app; not so lightweight; low code